# Server Client Button Game Loop

Tags: java, sockets

I have been creating a little game that involves the user entering numbers into the client generated but the server. I have it working for one loop but I am having trouble keeping the game going.

Once the user enters in their number the server will give points where needed, I have tried added a for loop around the lines below but this just prints uses the users first input.

How can I change the code so the server will issue a new number for the client to enter and not just use the users first number?

**Tried for looping this code**

```
                int n = light();
                String binString = lightBin(n);
                String check = Integer.toString(n);
                System.out.println(binString);

                outToClient.println("Turning on light " + n);

                fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("User pressed light " + fromclient);

                score = scoreCheck(check, fromclient);
                System.out.println("Score = " + score);
```

**Server Code**

```
    package networking;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Random;

    class TCPServer extends Thread
    {
        private static Object outToClient;


       public void run()
       {
           System.out.println ("The game is about to begin.");

       }

       public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
       {

            //declaring string variables
             String fromclient;
             int score= 0;
             //int outToClient;

             //new socket object, listening on port 5000
             ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket (3030);
             Server.setSoTimeout(10000);

             //prints when started and no client connected
             System.out.println ("The game is about to begin.");

             //infinate loop
             while(true) 
             {

                //listens for connection
                Socket connected = Server.accept();



                //outToClient.println(random);
                PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(connected.getOutputStream(),true);
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (connected.getInputStream()));


                int n = light();
                String binString = lightBin(n);
                String check = Integer.toString(n);
                System.out.println(binString);

                outToClient.println("Turning on light " + n);

                fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("User pressed light " + fromclient);

                score = scoreCheck(check, fromclient);
                System.out.println("Score = " + score);

          }
        }


       public static int scoreCheck(String check, String fromclient)
       {
           int score = 0;

           if (check.equals(fromclient))
               score++;
           else
               score--;

           return score;
       }

       public static String lightBin (int n)
       {
           String binString = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
            while (binString.length() < 16) {    //pad with 16 0's
                binString = "0" + binString;
            } 
            return binString;

       }

       public static int light ()
       {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(12) + 1;
            String check = Integer.toString(n);
            System.out.println("Turning on light " + n);
            return n;
       }

    }
```

**Client code**

```
    package networking;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    class TCPClient 
    {
     public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
     {

        String serverName = "localhost";
        int port = 3030;

        String FromServer;
        String ToServer;

        Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
        client.setSoTimeout(15000);

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        FromServer = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(FromServer);

        PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
        ToServer = inFromUser.readLine();


        while(true)
        {
            outToServer.println (ToServer) ;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Client code in while should be

```
 while (true) { // but you must specify some condition to stop the while
            FromServer = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println(FromServer);

            PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            ToServer = inFromUser.readLine();

            outToServer.println(ToServer);
            outToServer.flush();
        }
```

and your server side code

```
while (true) { // but you must specify some condition to stop the while
                outToClient.println("Turning on light " + n);
                outToClient.flush();
                fromclient = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("User pressed light " + fromclient);

                score = scoreCheck(check, fromclient);
                System.out.println("Score = " + score);
            }
```